# jQuery Mobile - difference between a page refresh and arriving via link for first time?

Tags: jquery, jquery-mobile

(I posted a similar question a couple weeks ago, but this situation/context is very different. This is not a duplicate question.)

I'm using jQuery Mobile 1.3.1 with jQuery 1.10.1.

I created clickable icon that, when clicked, should pop-up a dialog with some information. And it works great - sometimes. Other times I click it and nothing happens at all. At first there seemed to be no rhyme or reason as to when it would or would not work. Then I realized it only works after I refresh the page; it doesn't work when one first arrives that page.

So I'm guessing it has something to do with jQuery Mobile events, which I still seem to have a hard time wrapping my head around.

Here's a code snippet:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
   <meta charset="utf-8"/>
   <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
   <title>Some Company - Current Rates</title>

   <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/jquery.mobile.css" />
   <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/themes/cwm-mob-2.css" />
   <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/cwm-m.css" />
   <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/whhg.css" />

   <script src="js/jquery.js"></script>
   <script src="js/jquery.mobile.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
   <div data-role="page" id="jumbo" data-add-back-btn="true" data-theme="a">
     <div data-role="header" data-theme="b">
        <a href="index.html" data-icon="home">Home</a>
        <div class="logo">
           <center><img border='0' src='images/cmtransp.png' /></center>
        </div> <!-- logo -->
        <a href="#" data-role="button" data-rel="back" data-icon="back" class="ui-btn-right">Back</a>
        <div data-role="navbar" data-theme="a">
        <ul>
           <li><a href="guarantee.html">Guarantee</a></li>
           <li><a href="lockrate.php">Lock Your Rate</a></li>
           <li><a href="fixed.php">Current Rates</a></li>
        </ul>
     </div> <!-- navbar -->
  </div> <!-- header -->
  <div data-role="content">
     <ul data-role="controlgroup" data-type="horizontal" class="localnav">
        <li><a href="fixed.php" data-role="button" data-transition="fade">Fixed</a></li>
        <li><a href="arm.php" data-role="button" data-transition="fade">ARM</a></li>
        <li><a href="jumbo.php" data-role="button" data-transition="fade" class="ui-btn-active">Jumbo</a></li>
        <li><a href="hb.php" data-role="button" data-transition="fade">High Balance</a></li>
     </ul>
     <table data-role="table" id="rate_table" class="table-stripe table-stroke">
        <h2>30 Year Fixed - Jumbo <a href="#jumboinfo" data-rel="dialog" style="text-decoration: none"><i class="icon-info-sign"></i></a></h2>
```

The link in question is in the last line of the code snippet.

If one goes to a jQM page from a link, I know a series of events happens. What happens during a page refresh that does not happen when traveling to the page via a hyperlink for the first time? I've done reading on the jQuery Mobile site and other places, but I feel like I'm close but not quite there.

Thank you very much!

Comment: Links should work normally. However, use jquery v1.9.1

Comment: Can you post a jsfiddle and reproduce the issue? Are you using additional javascript code?

Comment: I have no problem downgrading to 1.9.1 and I will give that a try. Out of curiosity, however, is there an issue with 1.10.1?

Comment: Thank you both for your reply. I will post to jsfiddle in a bit and send the link. There isn't much in the way of additional javascript.

Comment: Hi i am facing similar problem and is wondering whether you already found a solution for this? Cheers

Comment: Unfortunately, not. I ended up giving up on jQuery Mobile for this project for various reasons (partially because it's too sluggish on many phones) and switched to zepto/jQTouch.